# How to redo on gedit

Tags: linux, gedit, redo

I'm new on Linux and new on gedit, of course. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo something, but undo too much and I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, which I used to on Windows, but it not redo for me.

So, how could I redo on gedit?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

extra characters

Comment: I always forget this. I go to the Gedit menu, and it's not there; so I come here again.

Comment: I keep doing ctrl + y out of habit